# How to polish heatbreak surface?

Tags: prusa-i3, replacement-parts, repair

I have a plastic squeezing up from the heatbreak thread. This indicates improper seal, but I have screwed everything together tightly. After disassembly, I realized I have a scuffed surface on my heatbreak. Sorry for the lack of photo, but I can't get it in focus. It's like if the bottom hole chipped out a little.

Is there any reasonably easy and cheap way to get it perpendicular and smooth again? Or should I just not bother and replace it altogether?